# Onelogin single sign out for ASP NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, onelogin, kentor-authservices

Is there are examples how to integrate OneLogin SSO (SAML) to ASP NET MVC application for example using Kentor Auth Owin extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Detailed steps (assuming your app is hosted at http://localhost/SampleApp):

1. Download the latest version of KentorIT’s AuthServices from https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices and open the Kentor.AuthServices.sln solution in Visual Studio.
2. Identify the SampleApplication project and copy its URL property, the ACS and SLS endpoints of the SampleApplication SP are based on that value
3. Go to you Onelogin, Apps > Add Apps, and search in the browser the [SAML Test Connector](https://support.onelogin.com/hc/en-us/articles/202673944-How-to-Use-the-OneLogin-SAML-Test-Connector) and select it.
4. At the configuration tab of the connector, add the Audience, Recipient, ACS and SLS values, if your SP base URL was http://localhost/SampleApp/ then you should add:
5. Audience: http://localhost/SampleApp/AuthServices
6. Recipient and ACS URL: http://localhost/SampleApp/AuthServices/Acs
7. Single Logout URL: http://localhost/SampleApp/AuthServices/Logout
8. Now is time to configure the SP AuthServices, edit the web.config file of the SampleApplication project. In the  section, enter the following values:

   1. entityId = http://localhost/SampleApp/AuthServices
   2. returnUrl = http://localhost/SampleApp
9. On the SSO tab of the Onelogin's connector you will find the Issuer, the SSO URL, the SLO URL, you will need to register those data on the web.config file as well as entityID, signOnUrl, logoutUrl on the identityProviders element. Also at Onelogin's SSO tab you will find the IdP x509 certificate, you may register it on Kentor's config as a signingCertificate. See Kentor documentation [here](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/blob/master/doc/Configuration.md#add-identityprovider-element)

Comment: Thanks! Works for me